# Saving Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, and am having a problem saving data. All items are saved except `published`, but I don't know why.

Here's my form:

```
<% form_for :product, @product do | fld | %>
    <span class="notice"><% if @product.errors.any? %><p class="error"><%= @product.errors.first[1] %></p><% end %></span>
    <table class="tbl-form" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="name" width="100">Code:</td>
          <td colspan="99"><%= fld.text_field :product_code, :class => "large" %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="5"/>
        <tr>
          <td class="name" width="100">Name:</td>
          <td colspan="99"><%= fld.text_field :name, :class => "large" %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="5"/>
        <tr>
          <td class="name" width="100">Start Week:</td>
          <td colspan="99"><%= fld.select :start_week, options_for_select(StockMovement.order("year DESC, week DESC").map { | val | [ "#{ val.year }/#{ val.week }", val.id] }, :selected => @product.start_week), :class => "ddl_SW" %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="5"/>
        <tr>
          <td class="name" width="100">Category:</td>
          <td colspan="99"><%= fld.select :product_category, options_for_select(ProductCategory.where("jos_product_category.published = 1").all.map { | val | [ val.name, val.id] }, :selected => @product.product_category)%></td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="5"/>
        <tr>
          <td class="name">Thumbnail:</td>
          <td colspan="99"><%= fld.text_field :thumbnail, :class => "large" %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="5"/>
        <tr>
          <td class="name">Original Image:</td>
          <td colspan="99"><%= fld.text_field :original_image, :class => "large" %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="5"/>
        <tr><td class="name">Publish:</td><td><span id="yesno"><%= fld.check_box :published, :class => "hide-chk" %><a id="true" alt="1" rel="product_published" class="yes">Yes</a><a id="false" alt="0" rel="product_published" class="no on">No</a></span></td></tr>
        <tr height="25"/>
        <tr class="btn-holder">
          <td colspan="99">
            <input type="image" src="/images/btn-save.png" class="img-btn"><a href="<%= admin_products_path %>" class="lnk-btn back">Back</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="5"/>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <% end %>
```

Here's my controller:

```
def new
    @product = Product.new

    if request.post? and params[:product]
      @product = Product.new(params[:product])
      @product.creator = logged_user['clientID']

      if @product.save
        #render :json => params[:product]
        redirect_to admin_product_show_url(:productID => @product.id), :notice => '<p class="success">You have successfully added a new product '"#{ @product.name }"'</p>'
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: specify what error occur to get right answer.

Comment: if you analyzed my form.. my field select which is published didn't save. all fields have been saved except in published

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `create` action to your controller, which is supposed to be the end point of the action of the form:

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(params[:product])
  if @product.save
    # set flash and redirect to somewhere
  else
    # set flash.now with a short message
    # and render the form here again (render :new)
  end
end
```

Comment: It is important to understand the underlying touchpoints. Request to new hits the new action in the controller which returns HTML containing a form. When the user submits the form a POST request hits the create action of the controller. The create action creates stuff in database and redirects you to the next page. If the create fails then it returns you HTML containing the original form with filled in values and inline error messages for you to submit again. The next submission after failure ends up on the create action again.

Comment: have you investigated/analyzed the development log? what are the attributes being received? What are the values being saved in the database (it is all logged). Do you pre-process your model attributes in anyway before save? Do you have attr_protected/attr_accessible in your model?